# Page Templates Used in Custom Post Type

Tags: templates, page-template, single, template-hierarchy, archive-template

The same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492233/hierarchical-custom-post-type-not-show-page-template-list-in-page-attributes) with no real response. They claim it's not possible but I have used plugins that accomplish this.

In WordPress I am having a problem figuring out how to use the default page post type templates in my custom post type and I think I am using the wrong search keywords everywhere because I having no luck...

I have a client that requested an "easy-to-maintain" method of displaying two other languages of their site. They said that a translator is out of the question because a lot of their context uses subtle slangs that only are used within certain communities of people.

I figured the easiest way to make a visible and friendly method of entry would be to accompany their current "pages" post type with two more of those language names. Problem is that their main "pages" post type has a drop down menu with a choice of four templates. I cannot seem to get their new post types to include these as well.

I have tried adding in the `single-name.php` and `archive-name.php` but this gives me only one of those four types, which is expected, I do understand that much. However, I have used plugins and themes that have custom post type templates in a drop down so I know its do-able. My post_type has all the usual stuff turned on i.e. ...

```
'capability_type' => 'page',
'hierarchical' => true,
'supports' => array('title','editor','custom-fields','page-attributes')
```

I also need to know if anyone who does know what to do here would suggest just simply making a custom meta box that looks for the page template stuff? Or is there a much smoother WordPress related function that I can use?

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: what is the name of the post type?

Comment: updated my question. I the post type names are irrelevant and named around the names of the languages. I have frenchsections and russiansections as the registered types.

Comment: I think you'll have to make your own meta box. shouldn't be too difficult though, [`get_page_templates`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Theme#Get_Custom_Page_Templates) will get the template names/files for your dropdown, and the [`single_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Filter_Hierarchy) filter will let you check the meta value and load the selected template instead of default.